# Cannot figure out why my script stops working. .

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple program of an etch-a-sketch. I have 2 buttons. 1 that resets the screen, the other makes a new screen and lets you pick the number of pixels in the draw area. The default size works, and the reset works. When I click the new button and set the number of pixels in the draw area updates but the eventlistener stops working and the mouse over won't change the the background color of the divs anymore. Here is my code:

```
const screen = document.querySelector('.screen')
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.clear-btn');
const newButton = document.querySelector('.new-btn');
var size = 64;

function createGrid(size) {
  document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].style["grid-template-columns"] = "repeat(" + size + ", 1fr)"
  document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].style["grid-template-rows"] = "repeat(" + size + ", 1fr)"
  console.log('createGrid');
  for (i = 0; i < size*size; i++) { 
    const grid = document.createElement('div');
    grid.classList.add('grid');
    grid.style.cssText = 'color: #cccccc; background: #cccccc; border: solid 1px lightgrey;';      
    screen.appendChild(grid);
  }
}

function reset() {
  for (i = 0; i < size*size; i++) { 
  grid[i].style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
  }
}

function newSize(){
  let userResponse = prompt("Please enter size of canvas: ", "");
  size = parseInt(userResponse);
  remove();
  createGrid(size);
}


function remove(){
  while (screen.firstChild) {
    console.log(size);
    screen.removeChild(screen.firstChild);
  }
}

createGrid(size);

clearButton.addEventListener('click', reset);
newButton.addEventListener('click', newSize);

var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid');
Array.from(grid).forEach((tile) => {
  tile.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    e.target.style.background = '#0d0d0d';

  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your event listener when you are creating the grid. You remove your grid, which the event original event listener has been attached and the newly created one doesn't have anything attached to it:

```
function createGrid(size) {
  document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].style["grid-template-columns"] = "repeat(" + size + ", 1fr)"
  document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].style["grid-template-rows"] = "repeat(" + size + ", 1fr)"
  console.log('createGrid');
  for (i = 0; i < size*size; i++) { 
    const grid = document.createElement('div');
    grid.classList.add('grid');
    grid.style.cssText = 'color: #cccccc; background: #cccccc; border: solid 1px lightgrey;';      
    screen.appendChild(grid);

    // Add listener to grid cell
    grid.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
       e.target.style.background = '#0d0d0d';
    })
  }
}
```

You might also have a look at [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) so that you don't have to add a listener per cell and can add it on the container.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you now have new divs. Your listener was attached to the original HTMLNodes, and now you added new ones, they do not have any listeners attached. The solution would be to:
- clean up the old listeners (in remove function)
- attach the new listeners (in newSize function)

Move the last part (from `var grid = document.getElementsByClassName...`) to a function, and call it at the end of new size function, something like this:

```
function atachListeners() {
  const grid = document.getElementsByClassName('grid');
  Array.from(grid).forEach(tile => {
    tile.addEventListener('mouseover', ...);
  });
};
```

Now, your newSize function is like this:

```
function newSize(){
  let userResponse = prompt("Please enter size of canvas: ", "");
  size = parseInt(userResponse);
  remove();
  createGrid(size);
  attachListeners();
}
```

And the remove gets the addition:

```
function remove() {
  removeTileListeners();
  while (screen.firstChild) {        
    screen.removeChild(screen.firstChild);
  } 
}
```

Implementing the removeListeners() method, I leave to you as homework :)

Comment: No problem. Do make sure to remove the listeners on each new drawing, otherwise they stay live, and they're a memory leak.

Comment: With event delegation he wouldn't have to remove the parent container at all and doesn't need to worry about managing listeners... Agree that removing listeners is a good habit to get into, but think that modern browsers do a good job at managing this. If going for best practice and memory management, event delegation seems like a no brainer.

Comment: Yes, delegation would certainly help, especially with OPs listener count. And unsubscribing is mandatory, otherwise the OP will start complaining how"browsers take 20 gigs of memory these days", as I've seen on social media yesterday :)